# "Invalid Where condition" when I try to search for a value that is accented ignoring accents in CRM 2011 with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I 'm trying to do a search for a contact. For example value "Café " which is stored in the name field , but when I search like "cafe" does not return any record .

I tried to do the following

```
using (ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
     {
       var query_where3 = from c in svcContext.ContactSet
                         join a in svcContext.AccountSet
                         on c.ContactId equals a.PrimaryContactId.Id
                         where c.FullName.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Contains("Café")
                         select new
                         {
                          account_name = a.Name,
                          contact_name = c.LastName
                         };
}
```

and appear the Exception with message saying **"Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method"**

Comment: UPDATE: Please do not interpret that I am wanting to find specifically the word "Café " or "Cafe" but rather as an example of a word that contains accents. You probably would have been the best example that would have changed the literal text by a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about

```
.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
```

, probably EF does not knows how to handle this method. Remove it and test just with

```
c.FullName.Contains("Café")
```

------------------------------------------------- Added in 2015-01-30 --------------------------------------------------

So man, the unique solution i can think about is list before you do the where condition. This way the you can use the normalize once this will be handled by linq 2 objects. try:

```
(from c in svcContext.ContactSet join a in svcContext.AccountSet
on c.ContactId equals a.PrimaryContactId.Id 
select new {a=a,c=c}    ).ToList()
.Where(c=>c.FullName.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Contains("Café"))
.Select( x=> select new  {
                          account_name = x.a.Name,
                          contact_name = x.c.LastName
                         };)
```

But that way can cause some overhead given that linq 2 obejects runs in application server memory, not in database server.

Comment: If i try with term "Café", CRM returns records, but when i change the term search to "Cafe"  (Without the accent) does not return any.

Comment: What server? If MS Sql Server this issue is caused by the collation of your field collation sufixed with (AI) means "accent insensitive" and its what you needs to solve this problem. collation  sufixed with "AS" means "accent sensitive" and will cause this kind of trouble. Try change the collation of the field FullName direct in sqlserver. But if you are using codefirst aproach search for "how to change collation in ef code first" and apply an collation that are sufixed with AI eg.: "Latin1_General_100_CS_AI"

Comment: This article explain better than me: http://www.talksharp.com/case-sensitive-fields-in-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: but, is a CRM SDK entity, i have not direct access to SQL (I do not think that I access access to SQL server to modify some of the CRM database too :P)

Comment: I'm really keen to reverse your down vote. So take a look in the addition that i made.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that functions on LinQ-CRM, the correct way to do the query is:

```
c.FullName == "someString" or c.FullName.equals("someString").
```

This is because you can't use functions or transformations on the left condition. You must use the attribute itself.

Your query will look like:

```
using (ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
     {
       var query_where3 = from c in svcContext.ContactSet
                         join a in svcContext.AccountSet
                         on c.ContactId equals a.PrimaryContactId.Id
                         where c.FullName == "Café" || c.FullName == "Cafe"
                         select new
                         {
                          account_name = a.Name,
                          contact_name = c.LastName
                         };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really deal with the accents with Linq to SQL in general ... and you are even more limited with what you can do with Linq to CRM. You cant modify the DB; unless you don't care about being supported. Then you could do something like : MAD suggested and to a db alter.

`ALTER TABLE Name ALTER COLUMN Name [varchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

I personally would not recommend that.

The best that I can come up with is getting the data as close as you can and filtering it from there inside a list or something similar. 
I have to do it all the time and it is a pain (and adds more overhead) but there is not really another workaround that I have found.

```
    //declare a dictionary 
    Dictionary<string, string> someDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> ();


    using (ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
     {
       var query_where3 = from c in svcContext.ContactSet
                         join a in svcContext.AccountSet
                         on c.ContactId equals a.PrimaryContactId.Id
                         where  c.FullName.Contains("Caf")
                         select new
                         {
                          account_name = a.Name,
                          contact_name = c.LastName
                         };
}
//then
    foreach(var q in query_where3)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(account_name)==false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact_name)==false)
    {
        someDictionary.Add(account_name, contact_name);
    }
    }
```

`//then you can add the .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD) to your dictionary`

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -1):

CRM's LINQ translator cannot handle the .Equals() method.

```
on c.ContactId equals a.PrimaryContactId.Id
```

Change the above line to below line.

```
on c.ContactId == a.PrimaryContactId.Id
```

Comment: After the change , still happens the same, if I do a search for " Cafe " does not return results, but if I put "Café " (with accent) CRM SDK returns the record because the CRM is accent - sensitive ( The same happens when accessing CRM. )

The problem is that I would limit the search results of many contacts that their names or business names containing accents